# Class returning itself in member functions in C++ DLL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

To use a class in a DLL, for compatibility between compliers, the method from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL#CppMatureApproach is used. This requires the class to be derived from an abstract class as the "interface" and override the functions of the abstract class. If the class for the DLL has functions which return a value of that class, how do you derive it and override the functions of an abstract class, as the functions must have the same return value and the value of an abstract class can not be returned. Apart from making a third, unexported class which can be easily converted to the original class that will be exported without data loss, how do you export the class from the DLL in a way that works with other compilers?

Original code: Only works with the same compiler.

```
#pragma once

#ifdef UNSIGNEDBIGINT_EXPORTS
#define UNSIGNEDBIGINT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define UNSIGNEDBIGINT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"

typedef std::deque<short int> list;

//Unsigned Bigint class.



class UNSIGNEDBIGINT_API Unsigned_Bigint
{
private:
    list digits;
    Unsigned_Bigint removeIrreleventZeros(Unsigned_Bigint);

    //Arithmetic Operations
    Unsigned_Bigint add(Unsigned_Bigint);
    Unsigned_Bigint subtract(Unsigned_Bigint);
    Unsigned_Bigint multiply(Unsigned_Bigint);
    Unsigned_Bigint divide(Unsigned_Bigint, bool);

    //Comparison Operations
    bool greater(Unsigned_Bigint);

public:
    Unsigned_Bigint();
    Unsigned_Bigint(int);
    Unsigned_Bigint(list);
    Unsigned_Bigint(const Unsigned_Bigint&);
    ~Unsigned_Bigint();
    inline list getDigits() const;

    //Overloaded Arithmetic Operators
    inline Unsigned_Bigint operator+(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline Unsigned_Bigint operator-(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline Unsigned_Bigint operator*(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline Unsigned_Bigint operator/(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline Unsigned_Bigint operator%(Unsigned_Bigint);

    //Overloaded Comparison Operators
    inline bool operator==(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline bool operator!=(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline bool operator>(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline bool operator<(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline bool operator>=(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline bool operator<=(Unsigned_Bigint);

    //Overloaded Asignment Operators
    inline void operator=(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline void operator+=(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline void operator-=(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline void operator*=(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline void operator/=(Unsigned_Bigint);
    inline void operator%=(Unsigned_Bigint);

    //Increment/Decrement
    inline Unsigned_Bigint& operator++();
    inline Unsigned_Bigint& operator--();
    inline Unsigned_Bigint operator++(int);
    inline Unsigned_Bigint operator--(int);

    //Exponent
    Unsigned_Bigint exponent(Unsigned_Bigint);

};

//Ostream
UNSIGNEDBIGINT_API inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Unsigned_Bigint);
```

**Edit**: There is also the issue that the abstract base class takes itself as a parameter, which is illegal as it is an abstract class. Using references requires large amounts of modifications in the code. Is there any alternative?

Comment: You are going to loose your time! Consider using an other library. There are tons of libraries implementing "big ints".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as the functions must have the same return value and the value of an abstract class can not be returned

Not really, C++ allows what are called [covariant return types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type), which means that a subclass which `override`s a method can replace the original return type with a subtype. But even if you didn't have that, you can return an instance of the subclass as the parent class. The problem you may have, though, is [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). If you are returning values (as opposed to references or pointers), additional members in the subclass will be lost when you use the parent class interface. You can use additional indirection (e.g. a struct with a pointer) or some other strategy to avoid it.

Comment: This does not fix the issue. The base class will be invalid if it is abstract because its methods take itself as a parameter, which being an abstract class, can not be a parameter.

Comment: @me' Right, so the problem was about the input parameters, not the output. Well, it's still the same, the inputs should be const references or pointers if you want to use polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

As the article you have linked states disadvantages of this approach:

> An abstract interface method cannot return or accept a regular C++
>   object as a parameter. It has be either a built-in type (like int,
>   double, char*, etc.) or another abstract interface. It is the same
>   limitation as for COM interfaces.

So maybe return a pointer to an asbtract interface of the class implementation?